# Enable the RelativeLayout inside the CollapsingToolbarLayout to remain on the screen after the toolbar is collapsed

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a RelativeLayout (**Temu Icon + Inside Android**) inside the CollapsingToolbarLayout. I want it to remain on the top of the screen when the toolbar is collapsed. The current effect is shown in the figures below.

**Before scrolling**
[image]

**After scrolling**
[image]

What I want is, after scrolling, the app still displays the RelativeLayout in the top white blank place.

Here is my code for the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:contentScrim="#EEEEF3"
        android:minHeight="56dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/backdrop"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="fitStart"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:src="@drawable/temu1"
                android:contentDescription="Temu Image"
                android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/backdrop"
                    android:layout_height="56dp">
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true">
                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="36dp"
                            android:layout_height="36dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/temulogo" />
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textSize="18dp"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                            android:text="Inside Android"
                            android:textColor="#ACACAC" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>


    </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="24dp">

        <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/card_margin">

            <LinearLayout
                style="@style/Widget.CardContent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Info"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/cheese_ipsum" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

        <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/card_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/card_margin"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/card_margin">

            <LinearLayout
                style="@style/Widget.CardContent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Friends"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/cheese_ipsum" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

        <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/card_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/card_margin"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/card_margin">

            <LinearLayout
                style="@style/Widget.CardContent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Related"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/cheese_ipsum" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```